# PBKDF2 Excel UDF and how to concatenate INT(i)

Tags: excel, vba, concatenation, pbkdf2

Recently I have been digging into cryptography and getting hashing and encryption functions working in Excel which I might use in a project I am working on.

I got simple hashing functions working using, for example:

```
Function Hash(ByVal plainText As String)

    Dim utf8Encoding As Object
    Dim hashManager As Object
    Dim hashBytes() As Byte

    Set utf8Encoding = CreateObject("System.Text.UTF8Encoding")
    Set hashManager = CreateObject("System.Security.Cryptography.SHA512Managed")
    hashBytes = utf8Encoding.GetBytes_4(plainText)
    hashBytes = hashManager.ComputeHash_2(hashBytes)

    Hash = Encode(hashBytes, edHex)

    Set utf8Encoding = Nothing
    Set hashManager = Nothing

End Function
```

To encode the result I have a created a function:

```
Function Encode(ByRef arrData() As Byte, ByVal dataType As endecodeDataType) As String

    Dim domDoc As Object
    Set domDoc = CreateObject("MSXML2.DOMDocument")
  
    With domDoc
        .LoadXML "<root />"
        Select Case dataType
            Case edBase64
                .DocumentElement.dataType = "bin.base64"
            Case edHex
                .DocumentElement.dataType = "bin.hex"
        End Select   
        .DocumentElement.nodeTypedValue = arrData
    End With

    Encode = domDoc.DocumentElement.Text

    Set domDoc = Nothing

End Function
```

These combined gives me perfectly verifiable results.
After more research I am now working on a PBKDF2 function:

- Specs: https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc2898
- Test vectors: https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6070

My first attempt was to look into 'Rfc2898DeriveBytes' as follows:

```
Dim hashManager As Object
Set hashManager = CreateObject("System.Security.Cryptography.Rfc2898DeriveBytes")
```

However this gives an error stating that the ActiveX component cannot be created.

Besides the error and for the sake of trying to understand the basics of PBKDF2, and learning to work with bits/bytes I have created the following function:

**Edit:** For now I'm only focusing on dkLen <= hLen

```
Function PBKDF2(ByVal password As String, _
                ByVal hashIterations As Long, _
                ByVal salt As String, _
       Optional ByVal encodeHash As hashEncoding = heBase64) As Variant

    Dim utf8Encoding As Object
    Dim hashManager As Object

    Dim hmacKeyBytes() As Byte
    Dim saltBytes() As Byte

    Dim hmacBytes() As Byte
    Dim tempBytes() As Byte

    Dim i As Long

    'Create encoding and crypto objects
    Set utf8Encoding = CreateObject("System.Text.UTF8Encoding")
    Set hashManager = CreateObject("System.Security.Cryptography.HMACSHA1")
   
    'Encode the key and salt to bytes
    hmacKeyBytes = utf8Encoding.GetBytes_4(password)
    saltBytes = utf8Encoding.GetBytes_4(salt)

    'Concatenate salt and INT(i) - INT (i) is a four-octet encoding of the integer i, most significant octet first.

    'Set the key in the crypto class
    hashManager.key = hmacKeyBytes

    'Compute HMAC from salt
    hmacBytes = hashManager.ComputeHash_2(saltBytes)
    tempBytes = hmacBytes

    'HMAC iterations
    For i = 1 To hashIterations
        tempBytes = hashManager.ComputeHash_2(tempBytes)
        hmacBytes = XorBytes(tempBytes, hmacBytes)
    Next i

    'ToDo: extract the first dkLen octets to produce a derived key DK
  
    'Base64, Hex, or Byte() output
    If encodeHash = heBase64 Then
        PBKDF2 = Encode(hmacBytes, edBase64)
    ElseIf encodeHash = heHex Then
        PBKDF2 = Encode(hmacBytes, edHex)
    End If

    Set hashManager = Nothing
    Set utf8Encoding = Nothing
  
End Function
```

Where I defined XorBytes as:

```
Function XorBytes(ByRef byte1() As Byte, ByRef byte2() As Byte) As Byte()

    Dim tempBytes() As Byte
    Dim len1 As Long
    Dim i As Long

    len1 = UBound(byte1)
    ReDim tempBytes(len1)

    For i = 0 To len1
        tempBytes(i) = byte1(i) Xor byte2(i)
    Next i

    XorBytes = tempBytes

End Function
```

I believe I have the basics correct. One thing I don't know how to solve is how to concatenate INT(i) to the salt. The specs state:

> U_1 = PRF (P, S || INT (i))

> Here, INT (i) is a four-octet encoding of the integer i, most significant octet first.

How do I implement this in my VBA code? I hope this gets me closer to this test vector:

- Input
- P = "password" (8 octets)
- S = "salt" (4 octets)
- c = 1
- dkLen = 20
- Output
- DK = 0c 60 c8 0f 96 1f 0e 71 f3 a9 b5 24 af 60 12 06 2f e0 37 a6 (20 octets)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After some more fiddling the function below returns output that I can verify with:

https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6070

**Enums**

```
Enum hmacAlgorithm
    HMAC_MD5
    HMAC_SHA1
    HMAC_SHA256
    HMAC_SHA384
    HMAC_SHA512
End Enum

Enum hashEncoding
    heBase64
    heHex
    heNone_Bytes
End Enum
```

**PBKDF2 Function**

```
Function PBKDF2(ByVal password As String, _
    ByVal salt As String, _
    ByVal hashIterations As Long, _
    ByVal algoritm As hmacAlgorithm, _
    Optional ByVal dkLen As Long, _
    Optional ByVal encodeHash As hashEncoding = heBase64) As Variant

'https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc2898 - PKCS #5: Password-Based Cryptography Specification Version 2.0
'https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6070 - PKCS #5: Password-Based Key Derivation Function 2 (PBKDF2) Test Vectors
'https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/PBKDF2

'DK = T1 || T2 || ... || Tdklen/hlen
'Ti = F(password, salt, c, i)
'
'F(Password, Salt, c, i) = U1 ^ U2 ^ ... ^ Uc
'
'U_1 = PRF (P, S || INT (i)) (INT (i) is a four-octet encoding of the integer i, most significant octet first.)
'U_2 = PRF (P, U_1)
'...
'U_c = PRF (P, U_{c-1})

Dim utf8Encoding As Object
Dim hashManager As Object

Dim hLen As Long
Dim noBlocks As Long
Dim noBlock As Long

Dim hmacKeyBytes() As Byte
Dim saltBytes() As Byte
Dim uboundSaltBytes As Long

Dim hmacBytes() As Byte
Dim tempBytes() As Byte
Dim outputBytes() As Byte

Dim i As Long
Dim j As Long

'Create utf8-encoding object
Set utf8Encoding = CreateObject("System.Text.UTF8Encoding")

'Create hmac object
Select Case algoritm
    Case HMAC_MD5
        Set hashManager = CreateObject("System.Security.Cryptography.HMACMD5")
    Case HMAC_SHA1
        Set hashManager = CreateObject("System.Security.Cryptography.HMACSHA1")
    Case HMAC_SHA256
        Set hashManager = CreateObject("System.Security.Cryptography.HMACSHA256")
    Case HMAC_SHA384
        Set hashManager = CreateObject("System.Security.Cryptography.HMACSHA384")
    Case HMAC_SHA512
        Set hashManager = CreateObject("System.Security.Cryptography.HMACSHA512")
End Select

'Check the length of the blocks to be generated
hLen = hashManager.HashSize / 8

'Calculate amount of blocks 'T'
If dkLen = 0 Then dkLen = hLen
noBlocks = Application.WorksheetFunction.Ceiling(dkLen / hLen, 1)
   
'Encode the key and salt to bytes
hmacKeyBytes = utf8Encoding.GetBytes_4(password)
saltBytes = utf8Encoding.GetBytes_4(salt)

'Set the key in the crypto class
hashManager.key = hmacKeyBytes

'Get the length of the salt, add 4 to concatenate INT(I)
uboundSaltBytes = UBound(saltBytes) + 4

'Loop T1 || T2 || ... || Tdklen/hlen
For i = 1 To noBlocks

    'Salt || INT(i)
    'INT (i) is a four-octet encoding of the integer i, most significant octet first.
    tempBytes = saltBytes
    ReDim Preserve tempBytes(uboundSaltBytes)
    noBlock = i

    'Calculate INT(i) of Salt || INT(i)
    For j = 3 To 0 Step -1
        tempBytes(uboundSaltBytes - j) = Int(noBlock / (255 ^ j))
        noBlock = noBlock - Int(noBlock / (255 ^ j)) * 255 ^ j
    Next j
     
    'Hash U1: Salt || INT(i)
    hmacBytes = hashManager.ComputeHash_2(tempBytes)
    tempBytes = hmacBytes
     
    'Hash, Xor: U1 ^ U2 ^ ... ^ Uc
    For j = 1 To hashIterations - 1
        hmacBytes = hashManager.ComputeHash_2(hmacBytes)
        tempBytes = XorBytes(tempBytes, hmacBytes)
    Next j
  
    'For the first block outputBytes() is empty
    If i = 1 Then
        outputBytes = tempBytes
    Else
        ConcatenateArrayInPlace outputBytes, tempBytes
    End If

Next i

'Extract the first dkLen octets to produce a derived key DK:
ReDim Preserve outputBytes(dkLen - 1)
  
'Base64, Hex, or Byte() output
If encodeHash = heBase64 Then
    PBKDF2 = Encode(outputBytes, edBase64)
ElseIf encodeHash = heHex Then
    PBKDF2 = Encode(outputBytes, edHex)
Else
    PBKDF2 = outputBytes
End If

Set hashManager = Nothing
Set utf8Encoding = Nothing
  
End Function
```

**HMAC function**

```
Function HMAC(ByVal plainText As String, _
    ByVal algoritm As hmacAlgorithm, _
    Optional ByVal key As String, _
    Optional ByVal decodeKey As keyDecoding = kdNone_String, _
    Optional ByVal encodeHash As hashEncoding = heBase64) As Variant

Dim hashManager As Object

Dim hashBytes() As Byte
Dim hmacKeyBytes() As Byte

'Create the specific hash manager based on the hash algoritm
Select Case algoritm
    Case HMAC_MD5
        Set hashManager = CreateObject("System.Security.Cryptography.HMACMD5") 'Returns 128 bits, 16 bytes
    Case HMAC_SHA1
        Set hashManager = CreateObject("System.Security.Cryptography.HMACSHA1") 'Returns 160 bits, 20 bytes
    Case HMAC_SHA256
        Set hashManager = CreateObject("System.Security.Cryptography.HMACSHA256") 'Returns 256 bits, 32 bytes
    Case HMAC_SHA384
        Set hashManager = CreateObject("System.Security.Cryptography.HMACSHA384") 'Returns 384 bits, 48 bytes
    Case HMAC_SHA512
        Set hashManager = CreateObject("System.Security.Cryptography.HMACSHA512") 'Returns 512 bits, 64 bytes
End Select

'Encode the plaintText to bytes
hashBytes = UTF8_GetBytes(plainText)

If key = vbNullString Then
  
    'Get the key generated by the hashManager
    hmacKeyBytes = hashManager.key

    'Calculate the hash
    hashBytes = hashManager.ComputeHash_2(hashBytes)

    'Return encoded result
    If encodeHash = heBase64 Then
        HMAC = "<Key>" & Encode(hmacKeyBytes, edBase64) & "<Key>" & vbCrLf & Encode(hashBytes, edBase64)
    ElseIf encodeHash = heHex Then
        HMAC = "<Key>" & Encode(hmacKeyBytes, edHex) & "<Key>" & vbCrLf & Encode(hashBytes, edHex)
    End If

Else

    'Decode and set the key
    Select Case decodeKey
    Case kdBase64
        hashManager.key = Decode(key, edBase64)
    Case kdHex
        hashManager.key = Decode(key, edHex)
    Case Else
        hashManager.key = UTF8_GetBytes(key)
    End Select

    'Calculate the hash
    hashBytes = hashManager.ComputeHash_2(hashBytes)

    'Return encoded result
    If encodeHash = heBase64 Then
        HMAC = Encode(hashBytes, edBase64)
    ElseIf encodeHash = heHex Then
        HMAC = Encode(hashBytes, edHex)
    End If

End If

Set hashManager = Nothing

End Function
```

**Test subroutine:**

```
Sub PBKDF2_Test()

Dim testvector As String
Dim pbkdf2_result As String

pbkdf2_result = PBKDF2("password", "salt", 1, HMAC_SHA1, 20, heHex)
testvector = "0c60c80f961f0e71f3a9b524af6012062fe037a6"
If pbkdf2_result = testvector Then Debug.Print "TV1: OK" Else Debug.Print "TV1: FAULT"

pbkdf2_result = PBKDF2("password", "salt", 2, HMAC_SHA1, 20, heHex)
testvector = "ea6c014dc72d6f8ccd1ed92ace1d41f0d8de8957"
If pbkdf2_result = testvector Then Debug.Print "TV2: OK" Else Debug.Print "TV2: FAULT"

pbkdf2_result = PBKDF2("password", "salt", 4096, HMAC_SHA1, 20, heHex)
testvector = "4b007901b765489abead49d926f721d065a429c1"
If pbkdf2_result = testvector Then Debug.Print "TV3: OK" Else Debug.Print "TV3: FAULT"

pbkdf2_result = PBKDF2("passwordPASSWORDpassword", "saltSALTsaltSALTsaltSALTsaltSALTsalt", 4096, HMAC_SHA1, 25, heHex)
testvector = "3d2eec4fe41c849b80c8d83662c0e44a8b291a964cf2f07038"
If pbkdf2_result = testvector Then Debug.Print "TV4: OK" Else Debug.Print "TV4: FAULT"

End Sub
```

I guess not the prettiest code, but it's a step forward. Feel free to improve!

Comment: where is the `endecodeDataType` defined? .. is it part of a library?

Comment: jsotola, I have editted the answer to include two enums that are used and the HMAC function