# VBA - concatenate byte array

Tags: arrays, vba, concatenation

I refer to this question: [PBKDF2 Excel UDF and how to concatenate INT(i)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45542723/pbkdf2-excel-udf-and-how-to-concatenate-inti/46393282#46393282)

OP did not provide the code for his "**ConcatenateArrayInPlace**"-Function, which is contained in his self-found solution to his original question. I am trying to create the function myself. However, I'm getting nowhere.

Does anybody know how the above-mentioned function might work?

Best,

Jasper

Answer (score 0):

I think I found a solution.

I changed the PBKDF2-Code as follows:

```
outputBytes = ConcatenateArrayInPlace(outputBytes, tempBytes)
```

(Instead of `ConcatenateArrayInPlace outputBytes, tempBytes`)

I inserted the following function:

```
Function ConcatenateArrayInPlace(ab1() As Byte, ab2() As Byte)
Dim ab3() As Byte
Dim i As Long

ab3 = ab1
ReDim Preserve ab3(UBound(ab1) + UBound(ab2))
For i = 0 To UBound(ab2)
    ab3(i + UBound(ab1)) = ab2(i)
Next

ConcatenateArrayInPlace = ab3

End Function
```

Now it works.

Best,

Jasper

Comment: i tried that code. since you got it working, where is the `hashEncoding` type defined?

Comment: OP did not post this either. However, I simply changed the dimension-property to `Optional ByVal encodeHash As String = "heHex"`.

In the function, i then used the following code:

`If encodeHash = "heBase64" Then
    PBKDF2 = ConvToBase64String(outputBytes)
ElseIf encodeHash = "heHex" Then
    PBKDF2 = ConvToHexString(outputBytes)
Else
    PBKDF2 = outputBytes
End If`

Answer (score 0):

I believe that the following would replicate the missing code:

```
Sub ConcatenateArrayInPlace(ByRef ab1() As Byte, ByRef ab2() As Byte)
    Dim origUBound As Long
    Dim i As Long
    origUBound = UBound(ab1)
    ReDim Preserve ab1(LBound(ab1) To origUBound + 1 + UBound(ab2) - LBound(ab2))
    For i = LBound(ab2) To UBound(ab2)
        ab1(origUBound + 1 + i - LBound(ab2)) = ab2(i)
    Next
End Sub
```

It will update the array specified as the first parameter by appending the array specified as the second parameter.